Setting Azure Monitoring alert 100% CPU for 30 minutes
So I have the below Terraform resource defined. I am not so sure what exactly the window size is. % for 30 straight minutes?
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "cpu_percent" {
  name                = "alert-${azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.pgsql_server.name}-cpupercent"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.pgsql_server.id]
  description         = "Action will be triggered Whenever the maximum cpu percent is greater than 100% for 30 minutes."
  window_size         = "PT30M"
  frequency           = "PT15M"
  severity            = 0

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
    metric_name      = "cpu_percent"
    aggregation      = "Maximum"
    operator         = "Equals"
    threshold        = 100
  }

Am I correct to assume that this means Azure checks the database every 15 minutes, and gives an alert in case the maximum CPU is 100?
